# I just upgraded to xcode to 4.5 and now can't install iOS5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I just upgraded my xcode to 4.5 but now when I try to install the iOS 5.1 simulator, I get the following error:

> [my user email] does not have access to iOS 5.1 Simulator.
>   Contact Apple Developer Support to resolve account access issues.

Has anyone seen this error before? I have been able to download and install 4.3 & 5.0 simulators with no issues. I was able to use 5.1 simulator in previous versions of xcode as well. I am on OSX 10.7.4.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Apple Developer Support?

Comment: I considered it, but figured contacting the developer community would offer a quicker solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to accept the new developer agreement in the member center on developer.apple.com. After that I could download the old simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I archived the previous version 4.4.1 in which I had the iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk and iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk (  Xcode display content :  Contents/Developer/Platforms/)

When XCode 4.5 installation is over , I transfered these 2 previous sdk into the 4.5 corresponding folder .... and then I could delete ( or keep ) the archive..

In the XCode iOS simulator, I have now all 3 sdk ...et voilà,  no need to pay for dev fees which are good if you want to access preview of FUTURE versions...