# Xcode 4.5: "does not have access to iOS 5.1 simulator"

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I upgrade Xcode from 4.4.1 to 4.5, but when I install iOS 5.1 Simulator, an error occurs: "does not have access to iOS 5.1 simulator". There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503973/i-just-upgraded-to-xcode-to-4-5-and-now-cant-install-ios5-1)
But, I don't know how to accept the new developer agreement? anybody can give me help? thanks.

BTW, I have got an free apple ID, I don't want to pay 99$/year.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you log into the Apple developer portal and accept the review of the license.
I had the same issue but after reviewing and accepting the license I was able to download and install everything.

In order to accept the new license, once logged in, you will find a yellow box in the top of the page with a sentence that will warn you that there is a newer version of the license you need to review. At the end of such sentence there's a link (it's coloured in blue). Click on that link and a page will open. Read the license, check the box at the end of the license content and issue "Accept".

That's all folks :)

Comment: Thank you, Fabiano. Now, maybe the most important thing for me is to pay 99$ to join iOS Developer Program, if not, Apple won't allow me to download and install iOS 5.1 Simulator.

Comment: Please, @ZhangZhiliang, accept my answer as the solution to this question (click the check mark right on the left of the answer itself). For what concerns the need to join the iOS developer program, I honestly don't think that's necessary but that's a topic a little bit different from the question you posted. Still, check this link out (http://pieces.dominikporada.com/post/31915100911/simulator) and, if you can't solve your problem, open a new question.

Comment: Very weird, i follow your step,but apple refuse me. Then I miss the page and there is no yellow box any more...   but i can download 5.1now.....    where can i review the license??

Comment: @谭叉叉 go to this page (https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), login and you will see the yellow box in the top of the page. The box is quite huge since its width is the page width. In the middle of it there is a sparkling blue link. Click that. If you can't see it, it means that you have already accepted the license and you are done.

Comment: I think only after join iOS Developer Program, we can see the yellow box. I haven't accepted the license, and I can't see the yellow box.

Answer (score 2):

No pain, no gain.
If you have payed $99 for iDP, you should go to member center to sign a new license before installing iOS 5.1 simulator in Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Do you mean after I pay 99$, I will be able to install iOS 5.1 Simulator in Xcode 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Xcode 4.5 comes with IOS6 Simulator pre-installed.